# Small question concerning the proof of the unbiased estimate of the population variance

Tags: statistics

The main purpose of this question is to check my understanding. As in I have an answer that I think is correct, but I'm not sure, since Stats is not my forte.

So given a random variable $X$, we take some samples from it and denote by $X_i$ the random variable "the $i$th observation from each sample" and denote by $\overline{X}$ the random variable the sample mean.

We're trying to show that:
$$E\left[\frac{1}{n-1}\sum(X_i-\overline{X})^2\right] = \sigma^2 \tag 1$$
where $\operatorname{Var}(X)=\sigma^2$.

Let $Y_i = X_i-\overline{X}$ and since $E[X_i]=E[\overline{X}]$ we have that $E(Y_i)=0$.

This means that the LHS of (1) becomes:

$$
\begin{align}
E\left[\frac{1}{n-1}\sum(Y_i^2)\right] & = \frac{1}{n-1}\sum E[Y_i^2] \\[8pt]
& = \frac{1}{n-1}\sum (\operatorname{Var}(Y_i)-(E[Y_i])^2) \\[8pt]
& = \frac{1}{n-1}\sum \operatorname{Var}(Y_i) \\[8pt]
& =\frac{1}{n-1}\sum \operatorname{Var}(X_i-\overline{X})
\end{align}
$$

Here is where I made the mistake of saying that $$\operatorname{Var}(X_i-\overline{X}) = \operatorname{Var}(X_i)+(-1)^2\operatorname{Var}(\overline{X}) = \sigma^2+\frac{\sigma^2}{n} = \sigma^2\frac{n+1}{n}$$

However, the proof I was following gave a longer calculation ending with $Var(Y_i)=\sigma^2\frac{n-1}{n}$ which then lead immediately to the desired result.
So I wondered where I had gone wrong.

My educated guess is that it is not true that $\operatorname{Var}(X_i-\overline{X})=\operatorname{Var}(X_i)+(-1)^2\operatorname{Var}(\overline{X})$ because $\operatorname{Var}(X+Y) = \operatorname{Var}(x)+\operatorname{Var}(Y)$ only if the random variables are independent and $X_i$ and $\overline{X}$ are not.

Have I explained my error correctly or is there another mistake in my calculations?

Thank you,
Diana

Comment: Welcome to math stack exchange!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\operatorname{var}(X_i-\bar X) = \operatorname{var}(X_i) + \operatorname{var}(\bar X) - 2\operatorname{cov}(X_i,\bar X) = \sigma^2 + \frac{\sigma^2} n - 2\frac{\sigma^2} n = \frac{n-1}n\sigma^2.
$$

The statement that $\operatorname{var}(X+Y) = \operatorname{var}(X)+\operatorname{var}(Y)$ **ONLY** if $X$ and $Y$ are independent is incorrect. It holds **if** they are independent, but not *only* if they are independent.  In fact it holds **if, and only if,** they are uncorrelated.  An example in which it holds when they are nowhere near independent is this: suppose $X$ is uniformly distributed on the set $\{-1,0,1\}$ and $Y=X^2$. Then $\operatorname{var}(X)=2/3$ and $\operatorname{var}(Y)=2/9$ and $\operatorname{var}(X+Y) = 2/3 + 2/9$, but clearly they are not independent.

Comment: Thank you, Michael, for confirming my suspicions and for correcting my error!